# What can cause a browser (Chrome) to generate a download

Tags: javascript, html, http, google-chrome

I am playing with experimental webRequest API from chrome.

The goal is to identify web request that will pop up a download window.

For the moment, my filtering is based on file extension and that filters pretty well, but I want to block any kind of file, even if they don't have an extension.

I am pretty sure HTTP Response Headers can help me identify the responses that will be treated as download.

Have you any idea of which one(s) will trigger it?

Thanks,

Florent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a Content-Disposition which specifies *attachment*.

[edit]
You may also have to look for a content-type of *application/force-download*.
[/edit]

Comment: So if I dump every response that have Content-Disposition header, i will just dump "downloadable" files?

Comment: It will dump those that are specifically marked as a download... however, if you really want to stop everything you may want to whitelist by content-type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTML header that looks like this:

```
Content-type: application/pdf
```

You can use look at that information, and only whitelist (as opposed to blacklist) the good content-types.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers give a functionality to specify how to handle files with specific extension beyond the common once (html,php,asp, etc). Every user can customize the experience. For example, one user, an mp4 file may be directly played in it by using some plug-in while other may offer it for download.

You will probably have to play with your calculation and assume that files with out typical web-page extensions are downloadable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe anything with a content-type that the browser doesn't understand will force it to download. Example:

```
$mimeType = 'application/force-download';
```